# Can this system of congruences be solved?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

\begin{equation}
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    2x\equiv7\mod9 \\
    5x\equiv2\mod6
  \end{array}\right.\,.
\end{equation}
Can this system of congruences be solved?
I notice that $(9,6) = 3 \ne 1$ so I can't apply the Chinese theorem of remainders, but this doesn't imply that it can't be solved, so I thought to rewrite the second equation in two different equations, like this:

\begin{equation}
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    2x\equiv7\mod9 \\
    x\equiv0\mod2 \\
    5x\equiv2\mod3
  \end{array}\right.\,.
\end{equation}

But the problem still here: $(9,3) = 3 \ne 1$, so it can be solved or is it impossible?

Comment: Well, you could always try to solve it to find out.

Comment: If you want a more general approach:  work with the gcd.  If a solution existed, we'd have $2x\equiv 7\pmod 3$ AND $5x\equiv 2\pmod 3$.  Is that possible?  Now there are only three values to test...

Comment: @lulu why $2x \equiv 7 \pmod3 $? 3 is the gcd?

Comment: Right.  Since $3$ divides $9$ we get that $2x\equiv 7 \pmod 9\implies 2x\equiv 7 \pmod 3$.  Similarly for the $\pmod 6$ congruence.

Comment: @lulu I got it! thanks.

Comment: By the theorem in the linked dupe it is solvable $\iff 2\cdot 2\equiv 7\cdot 5\pmod{3},\,$ so it's unsolvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9$ and $6$ are both multiples of $3$.

$2x\equiv7\pmod9\implies 2x\equiv1\pmod3$

$5x\equiv2\pmod6\implies 2x\equiv2\pmod3$

$1\equiv2\pmod3$ is a contradiction, so the system cannot be solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The system of congruences  $\begin{cases}
x\equiv \alpha\mod a,\\ x\equiv \beta \mod b,
\end{cases}$ has a solution if & only if  $\alpha\equiv \beta\mod\gcd(a,b)$.

So, solve each congruence independently from the other, and check whether the condition is satisfied.